# Network Services Account

Tags: .net-2.0

HI All,

I have a .NET application which connects to a Web Service. Application pool for the Web service works under Network Services account. Everything was working fine till yesterday and somehow it started giving error today. When I changed the application pool account from Network Services to an Admin level account, everything started working fine.

As far as I know, Network Services account has top level privilage on the local system.

My question is, can Network Services account lose its permissions? If yes, how to give those permissions back again?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Network service account has no top level privilege on the local system. True is, the Network Service account has minimum privileges like a user in the users group has.

It is most likely someone has changed the privileges for some files and/or folders on your system, so that the network sertvice account is not permitted anymore.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684272%28VS.85%29.aspx